# Chromium webbrowser freezes when start (ERROR:nss_util.cc(397))

Tags: 11.10, chromium

For some reason, while I was browsing the chrome web store (and about 9 other tabs), the browser got frozen (the window got darker, meaning it was processing). I also had just put my google-password in the preferences to sync everything on chrome.

I have an intel i3, and I never had problems with performance, so I think it's not a hardware issue.

I started it in incognito mode, on the terminal, but it still get frozen after about 3 seconds. The output was:

```
$ chromium-browser --incognito
[3:3:848113656:ERROR:nss_util.cc(397)] Error initializing NSS without a persistent database: libsoftokn3.so: cannot open shared object file: Permission denied
[6:6:848139429:ERROR:nss_util.cc(397)] Error initializing NSS without a persistent database: libsoftokn3.so: cannot open shared object file: Permission denied
[7:7:848160628:ERROR:nss_util.cc(397)] Error initializing NSS without a persistent database: libsoftokn3.so: cannot open shared object file: Permission denied
[11:11:848165760:ERROR:nss_util.cc(397)] Error initializing NSS without a persistent database: libsoftokn3.so: cannot open shared object file: Permission denied
[10:10:848165760:ERROR:nss_util.cc(397)] Error initializing NSS without a persistent database: libsoftokn3.so: cannot open shared object file: Permission denied
[18:18:848206961:ERROR:nss_util.cc(397)] Error initializing NSS without a persistent database: libsoftokn3.so: cannot open shared object file: Permission denied
[24:24:848354909:ERROR:nss_util.cc(397)] Error initializing NSS without a persistent database: libsoftokn3.so: cannot open shared object file: Permission denied
[26:26:848385315:ERROR:nss_util.cc(397)] Error initializing NSS without a persistent database: libsoftokn3.so: cannot open shared object file: Permission denied
[30:30:848413750:ERROR:nss_util.cc(397)] Error initializing NSS without a persistent database: libsoftokn3.so: cannot open shared object file: Permission denied
[34:34:848414414:ERROR:nss_util.cc(397)] Error initializing NSS without a persistent database: libsoftokn3.so: cannot open shared object file: Permission denied
```

I'm on Firefox now. *[update: I'm on Chrome now. The problem is only with Chromium]*

Any idea what's wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the only solution is switch to Google Chrome, what I did, and everything is fine now.

Answer (score 1):

This has been fixed in Chromium build >= 104421 or Chrome version >= 15:
http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=91962#c36

Consider a) using a ppa:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:chromium-daily/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install chromium-browser
```

..or b) use the proposed repository in ubuntu

..or c) the evil workaround (comment #31 or #32):
http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=91962#c31

Bug tracking at launchpad: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/chromium-browser/+bug/881607